# Linking Records : Matching records without primary key - foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, excel, logic, relational-database

I need to automate one manual system, where user will upload two different excel file.

1. First excel file will have some columns say . [ customer_id, location,
   service_date ]. These are service data.
2. Second excel file will have columns say. [ payment , customer_id,
   location, service_date, payment_date ] so on. These are payment data against service

I suggested to add one extra column in excel say service_id that uniquely identify the each record. As because all column (*customer_id, location, service_date*) combine together are not unique. But they are not agree, to add even a single column in service excel file or in payment excel file.

So only option I have is that to using all columns combine as primary key to cross check payment excel against service excel.

Is there any other work around or batter solution for this problem?

Comment: If service date includes hour, maybe you can check if it is unique or not combining with customer_id?

Comment: Yeah, but hour is not there in excel, and then adding hour column, rather to add service_id itself. *customer_id, location, service_date* can get repeated too...

Comment: WTF you need to be a magician to solve this :D

Comment: May be, searching that magician on stackoverflow ;-)